# Matplotlib uses broken pdfmarks in latex

Tags: matplotlib, pdflatex, xelatex

I have a really weird problem:

```
plt.xlabel("$t$[ms]")    
plt.ylabel("$\dot{q}$[deg]")  
plt.axvline(x=span2Stop,lw='0.3',c='0.5')
plt.axvspan(spanStart, spanStop, facecolor='0.9', alpha=1,edgecolor='0.9',lw=0)
plt.annotate('11ms',fontsize='9', xy=(11, -500),xytext=(2, -500),verticalalignment='center',arrowprops=myarrow)
plt.annotate('13ms',fontsize='9', xy=(13, 1000),xytext=(2, 1000),verticalalignment='center',arrowprops=myarrow)
plt.annotate('17ms',fontsize='9', xy=(17, -500),xytext=(20, -500),verticalalignment='center',arrowprops=myarrow)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(imagePath + "snapAHVjoints.pdf")
plt.savefig(imagePath + "snapAHVjoints.svg")
plt.show()
```

generates a nice looking picture. But `plt.axvline(x=span2Stop,lw='0.3',c='0.5')` causes a broken pdfmark in the exported pdf if included in latex as a pdf. I spent ages to find that.

Compiled with xelatex to pdf. The problem does not seem to be related to the loaded packages (to be honest I didn't try to  to disable hyperref but tested almost all options I found).

Any Idea what's wrong with that?

Comment: After turning your example into a self-contained compilable one (removed arrowprops, used numbers for span ranges) and making the width of the vertical line integer (`lw=3`), this works on my system --- `matplotlib 1.1.0` and `pdflatex` from `TeXLive2009` on Ubuntu Lucid. Could you provide an <a href="http://sscce.org/">SSCCE</a>?

Comment: I don't see a "Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example" below. Could you turn your code into something that other people can simply copy and paste, so they can see what happens with the pdf. For example, at least "myarrow" and "imagePath" make this example not self-contained.

Comment: Sorry not yet. I have to finish my thesis tomorrow and the document is 30 pages. Sorry. I'll try to do that next week if of any interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lw='0.3'` should be `lw=0.3` Nevertheless, no broken pdf should be exported. If you export it as eps matplotlib complains, so I recognized it that way

Is that a bug or am I again getting wrong soem pythonic things?